# how to save data in byte format as 32bits in ubuntu 64 bits using python?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am using python 3+ and ubuntu 18.04 64 bits. Every time I save data using either np.save or pickle and loading data, the data is load as float64. However I am working with np arrays in float32.

How can I use np save or pickle (what is almost the same) to save data as float32. Thus I will save space in disk.

Comment: `np.save/load` should load the arrays with the dtype as they were saved.  Have you double checked the arrays before saving?

Comment: yes. when saving dtype is float32. But when loading data dtype is float64

Comment: That's not what happens on my computer (same ubuntu).  The dtype is preserved.  How about other dtypes, e.g. `uint8`, 'float128', etc?

Comment: I got it! I was transforming a list to np array using np.array(list). When checking dtype it was float32. However data was saved and read as float64. When doing data format explicitly np.array(list, dtype='float32') it works. Now it saves and reads as float32